# Innerhtml dynamic image loading not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image

```
`<img src="../images/Editing-Edit-icon.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".editButton"  id="deleteBtn"/>`
```

and a button

```
`<button onclick="loadImage()">`
```

I am trying to load img inside a div on button click, like the follows:

```
function loadImage(){
 cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("deleteBtn").value;
}
```

But it is not working. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function loadImage(){
    cell1.innerHTML = '<img src="'+document.getElementById("deleteBtn").src+'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `src` of the image , you must get `src` property from `img` tag

```
 cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("deleteBtn").src;
```

Then if you have load image with deleteBtn src property you must set :

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<img src='" + document.getElementById("deleteBtn").src + "' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid *innerHTML* by [using *cloneNode*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4) to clone the image element:

```
var clone = document.getElementById('deleteBtn').cloneNode();
clone.id = /* whatever */
// Change other properties as required
cell.appendChild(clone);
```

Incidentally, closing empty HTML elements with `/>` is just putting junk in the markup.

Comment: multiple calls to this code would result in many copies of the image, rather than simply replacing the current one.